# Write data to NSPasteboard and paste into Excel split by column and line

Tags: excel, swift, macos, nspasteboard

Regarding use of NSPasteboard by Swift. I want to write an OS X program to copy NSTableView data and paste it into Excel split by row and column, to match Excel format. Current code:

```
@IBAction func copyDataButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    let pasteBoard = NSPasteboard.generalPasteboard()

    pasteBoard.clearContents()
    pasteBoard.writeObjects(["data to excel"])


}
```

I don't know how to adjust NSPasteBoardWriting data in NSPasteboard to insert a ASCII or ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had find the answer, you can construct the string use \t for tab a column, use \n to change line.

```
let tsvString = "data to excel\n then change line \t then tab a column"

let pasteBoard = NSPasteboard.general()

pasteBoard.clearContents()
pasteBoard.writeObjects([tsvString as NSString])
```

Comment: For some reason `\t` doesnt work. Do you have any reference to the documentation?